# How do I make my custom error message prevent form from submitting instead of displaying rails error page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have the following model that triggers an error if someone tries to use a blacklisted phrase when creating a slug. As the code currently is, it will allow the form to be submitted and then display a rails error page with the error message below.

How do I make it so that the the form is prevented from being submitted and displays the error/reason for the inability to submit on the actual form page?

```
class LandingPage < ActiveRecord::Base

validate :check_for_blacklisted_slug

private

def check_for_blacklisted_slug
  blacklist = ['not this', 'or this', 'def not this']
  blacklist.each do |phrase|
    if self.slug == phrase.parameterize
      errors.add(:slug, "This slug is reserved. Please pick another slug.")
    end
  end
end
end
```

Comment: im confused now because when I add the 's' to the end it throws an argument error. "You need to supply at least one validation"

But the code as it is currently 'validate' it actually runs blacklisted slug method'

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with rails per se. You need a jQuery for that *(or js or any js frameworks)*

First, you create a controller with action where you will validate your input and which responds with 400x status code if the input is invalid.
With jQuery on `.focusout` you make an AJAX request to your action if request is successful you do nothing, otherwise you add errors below your input.

That will involve lots of googling and reading documentation, but I hope I at least showed you the way.

*And in case you're wondering if this all necessary for such a simple task? Unfortunately, yes. It will become a lot easier since you wrap your head around that*

Comment: [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin is really good at this.